# get the name of clicked custom (Menu) CommandBarControl in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have added custom context menu in vba excel, I want to get name of clicked menu item. I am using excel 2010 version.

Comment: `Commandbars.Actioncontrol.Name` should do it.

Comment: Its working. Thanks.